# Loop MySQL column values as variable

Tags: php, mysql

The following code is intended to use levenshtein() to compare a user-input word to the values in a column of a MySQL table:

```
    $searched=$_POST['searched'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `word_list`;";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    $title = $row['word'];
    $sound = levenshtein($searched, $title);
    if ($sound < 4) {
    echo $title;
}

?>
```

My confusion stems from the mechanics of actually looping in the values of the "word" column of the table as a variable for the second string int he levenshtein function.

Ultimately, I'd like to loop the values from that column into the $title variable, and echo the values that produce a levenshtein distance less than 4, but I cannot seem to return any output.

Comment: I don't understand your question. `while` or `for` doesn't really matter. Use `break;` if you want to exit the while prematurely.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `while` loop is correct in your example. But you are mixing the `mysql` and the `mysqli` extension:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
...
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
```

You'll have to use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` instead.

---

Also you are missing a closing `}` at the end of the while loop. The complete example should look like this:

```
$searched = $_POST['searched'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `word_list`;";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    $title = $row['word'];
    $sound = levenshtein($searched, $title);
    if ($sound < 4) {
        echo $title;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you; this clarified things a bit, but now I'm receiving a 500 error, so at least now I have some idea of where to go with this.